# Trying to change BorderThickness in DataGrid ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, mahapps.metro

Im using a package called MahApps Metro, I'm trying to change the style of my DataGrid to change the default BorderThickness of the ColumnHeader.

The MahApps metro DataGrid control can be found here: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml

The part I'm trying to access with my custom style is:

```
<Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
```

Currently I have:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="GeledigdHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#953735"/>
</Style>
```

This changes the color properly but now I want to change the Thickness, just using Property="BorderThickness" does not work, obviously..

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look at the style there you are given no explicit access to the BorderThickness via binding. Since you have the style you can add this line to it

```
<Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
```

Comment: I'd rather not edit the MahApps metro control itself because I'd have to do it again after every update

Comment: Well the only alternative is to change the control template in your style or do this in code, finding the element by name or something of that construct I think. Although I believe best practice is if you dont like a certain control template you add your own style to change that control template. Since this is github code, you can also ask why the column header doesn't expose the border thickness.